# Calculate the average of some elements in sublists

Tags: python, sorting, python-3.x, average, sublist

I am trying to find the averages of some elements in a nested list.

```
data=[['Alan', 8, 4, 5], ['Jog', 10, 1, 2], ['Rhys', 7, 8, 8], ['Sam', 7, 8, 9], ['Tom', 5, 6, 9], ['Tommo', 5, 4, 6]]
```

I need to calculate the average of the numbers in each sub-list and order the sub-lists in descending order of the calculated averages in Python 3.
How do I output the list with the names and their averages next to them?
I have tried the avg function but got stuck.

Comment: Example output please?

Comment: What `avg` function?

Comment: [['Alan', 5], ['Jog', 4], ['Rhys', 7], ['Sam', 8], ['Tom', 6], ['Tommo', 5]] but in descending order i.e [['Sam', 8], ['Rhys', 7], ['Tom', 6], ['Alan', 5],['Tommo', 5],['Jog', 4]]

Comment: Presumably this is the same GCSE coursework we've been inundated with for months now - if so, note that asking **this is cheating** (although kudos for doing so under your own name). It's also a bad SO question - where's your code, and what precisely is the problem with it?

Comment: Is this a GCSE question?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, @Jonrsharpe I don't recognise it as one in my GCSE course.`

Comment: @Tim, ok thanks for letting me know, safe to un-delete the answer so!

Comment: @Tim it seems very familiar - http://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/2gawvg/gcse_computing_programming_tasks_14_16_year_olds/ (choice 2)

Comment: @jonrsharpe ahh, I did computer science not computing, that could be the difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension and unpacking operation :

```
>>> [[name,sum(num)//3] for name,*num in data]
[['Alan', 5], ['Jog', 4], ['Rhys', 7], ['Sam', 8], ['Tom', 6], ['Tommo', 5]]
```

Or if you want the result as float you can use `/` instead of `//` :

```
>>> [[name,sum(num)/3] for name,*num in data]
[['Alan', 5.666666666666667], ['Jog', 4.333333333333333], ['Rhys', 7.666666666666667], ['Sam', 8.0], ['Tom', 6.666666666666667], ['Tommo', 5.0]]
```

Comment: I'd suggest `round`ing not `//`ing - 7 and 7.66666666 is a reasonable difference, and rounding up is much preferred normally.

Answer (score 0):

```
data=[['Alan', 8, 4, 5], ['Jog', 10, 1, 2], ['Rhys', 7, 8, 8], ['Sam', 7, 8, 9], ['Tom', 5, 6, 9], ['Tommo', 5, 4, 6]]
datam = []

for i in data:
    datam += [[i[0],sum(i[1:])/len(i[1:])]]

datam.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
```

First this find the average of the data, and adds it to the list `datam`, as well as the name.

Then it sorts this by the second item (index 1, the mean). It also reverses it, to go from Hight to Low.

printing this gives the following:

```
[['Sam', 8.0], ['Rhys', 7.666666666666667], ['Tom', 6.666666666666667], ['Alan', 5.666666666666667], ['Tommo', 5.0], ['Jog', 4.333333333333333]]
```